# Android Studio Beta v0.8.14 not showing in start menu

Tags: android-studio

I have downloaded Android Studio Beta v0.8.14 and followed the steps to install it on Windows 7 from the link:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio

The link says to launch studio.exe and follow the installation wizard. But the zip file contains studio.exe file in  bin folder and directly launches Android Studio(after resolving all issues). There is no installation wizard and so it is not showing up in start menu. I don't have any others problems though but just want to make sure that everything is all right.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android studio doesn't have an installer. you just unzip the file and its ready to go. You are not missing anything.

However, if you want to you can adda start menu shortcut for the .exe file if you want, that doesn't have an installer.

Comment: I'm just going to use it as it is. Thank you.